# EntityManager detached entity passed to persist after flush when objects attributes are set earlier

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I was writing a feature to insert records from XML file to MySQL database in Spring using *EntityManager* and *JpaContext*.
I was trying on two files, one with 50 records, second with duplication of them up to 100 records. In my function, for every 50 records persisted, I call *flush()*, *clear()* and print message.
I'm uploading Users and they require to encode the password and properly set a **Role** attribute that is in a different table as a key.
I have a *for* loop that gets the User from the list and whole operation with entityManager starts.
Firstly, I had that user setting in the same loop.

```
public void insertInBatch(List<User> usersList) {
        EntityManager entityManager = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(User.class);
        setUsersRoleAndEncodePasswords(usersList);

        for(int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++){
            User user = usersList.get(i);
            // Setting User attributes
            Role role = roleRepository.findByRole("ROLE_USER");
            user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(role)));
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

            entityManager.persist(user);

            if(i % 50 == 0 && i > 0){
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
                System.out.println("****\t Loaded " + i + " records from " + usersList.size() + "\t****");
            }
        }
    }
```

And that code worked for 50 and 100 records files.
As Users are taken from the List, I wrote a function that sets the attributes to make code cleaner and called it before the *for* loop.

```
 public void insertInBatch(List<User> usersList) {
        EntityManager entityManager = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(User.class);
        setUsersRoleAndEncodePasswords(usersList); // Setting User attributes

        for(int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++){
            User user = usersList.get(i);
            entityManager.persist(user);
            if(i % 50 == 0 && i > 0){
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
                System.out.println("****\t Loaded " + i + " records from " + usersList.size() + "\t****");
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUsersRoleAndEncodePasswords(List<User> usersList){
        for (User user : usersList){
            Role role = roleRepository.findByRole("ROLE_USER");
            user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(role)));
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        }
    }
```

And this works fine for 50 record file, but **does not** for 100, throwing an expection right after the message is shown (at 50 records file, message is not shown).

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: stanislaw.appdemo.user.Role
```

Why is this, when the code logic is nearly the same, and both works for 50 records? I'm assuming that *flush()* or *clear()* have to modify the usersList somehow, but how? Full logs from error.

```
Hibernate: insert into user_role (user_id, role_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_role (user_id, role_id) values (?, ?)
****     Loaded 50 records from 100 ****
Hibernate: insert into user (active, email, last_name, name, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-02-01 22:50:01.612 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.view.RedirectView        : View name 'redirect:', model {}
2020-02-01 22:50:01.612 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: stanislaw.appdemo.user.Role
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:732)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:694)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:688)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminServiceImpl.insertInBatch(AdminServiceImpl.java:70)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$158389f3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7bf6db3c.insertInBatch(<generated>)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminPageController.importUsersFromXML(AdminPageController.java:133)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminPageController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$413b934d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminPageController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$deac85ce.importUsersFromXML(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: stanislaw.appdemo.user.Role
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:726)
    ... 136 more
2020-02-01 22:50:01.618 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/admin/users/1", parameters={}
2020-02-01 22:50:01.619 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to stanislaw.appdemo.admin.AdminPageController#showAdminAllUsersPage(int, String, Model)
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, user0_.active as active2_1_, user0_.email as email3_1_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_1_, user0_.name as name5_1_, user0_.password as password6_1_ from user user0_ limit ?
Hibernate: select count(user0_.user_id) as col_0_0_ from user user0_
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_2_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_0_1_, role1_.role as role2_0_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_2_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_0_1_, role1_.role as role2_0_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_2_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_0_1_, role1_.role as role2_0_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
2020-02-01 22:50:01.626 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-02-01 22:50:01.626 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'admin/users', model {totalPagesNumber=86, currentPageNumber=1, usersList=[stanislaw.appdemo.user.User@915e2d3, stanislaw.appdemo.user.User@3736d882, stanislaw.appdemo.user.User@38d60924], recordCounterStart=0, searchParam=}
2020-02-01 22:50:01.626 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/users.jsp]
2020-02-01 22:50:01.630 DEBUG 12592 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `entityManager.clear()` will remove all entities from persistence context. This includes `Role` entities that are already assigned to `User`entities

In first version of code `Role` assigned to `User` always remains in persistence context until entityManager.persist() is called:

```
//1) now role is in persistence context            
user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(role)));
user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
//2) so persisting User with Role is not an issue
entityManager.persist(user);
```

In second example, `Role` is actively removed from persistence context:

```
//1) now we have role in persistenceContext 
EntityManager entityManager = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(User.class);
setUsersRoleAndEncodePasswords(usersList); // Setting User attributes

for(int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++){
    User user = usersList.get(i);
    //2) for 50 first Users this will succeed, because role is in persistence context
    //but for after that it will fail, because role will be removed in 3)
    entityManager.persist(user);
    if(i % 50 == 0 && i > 0){
        entityManager.flush();
        // 3) after this call persistence context is empty, role will not be there
        entityManager.clear();
        System.out.println("****\t Loaded " + i + " records from " + usersList.size() + "\t****");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed `for` loop to `while()` with `Iterator`, get User with `iter.next()`,  after persisting it I remove the User with `iter.remove()` and inside the if statement I call my `setUsers` method on the `usersList` with removed elements.